# How to add skrollr-body tag without affecting page height?

Tags: javascript, skrollr

Firstly, skrollr has proved very helpful, thanks to those responsible.

I have tried to add the skrollr-body tag around all elements apart from the fixed background, which I think I have done correctly, so it works on mobile, but it is cropping the top of the page and i can't tell why.

Page without Skrollr-body (how I want it to look) - http://olivershilling.co.uk/demo.html

Page with Skrollr-body (causing the problem) - http://olivershilling.co.uk/demo-2.html

Any ideas? I may just disable it for small screens otherwise.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to rethink your CSS. `#welcome` has `height:100%` which is now relative to `#skrollr-body` which has a dynamic height depending on the content.

Comment: Prinzhorn, I am having the same issue, and I'm not 100% clear on what I should do. My first section only has a logo in it, so I have to force that section to be 100% height, but using the Skrollr-body ID I have the same issue with that section collapsing down to just he height of the content. I wasn't sure what you meant by rethink your CSS.

Comment: Hmm.. I thought this was a website where folks can share issues AND CORRECTIVE ACTION for others who may have the same issue?  Code, where's the code?  As it currently stands this question is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, the way I got around it is by setting the `#skrollr-body` element height to `100%` using javascript after the DOM is loaded.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#skrollr-body").css("height", "100%");
});
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: @Prinzhorn no, for some reason it breaks scrolling on mobile :(